# Reference leaks in copy constructor

Tags: java, arrays, constructor, copy-constructor

I understand what is the reference leak and can deal with it, but I'm confused now when I had to write a copy constructor. Does the copy constructor cause leaks too?

```
public class Student {

    private final int ID;
    private final String studentName;
    private double[] Grades = new double[5];

    // constructor:
    public Student(int ID, String Name, double[] quizGrades) { 

        this.ID = ID;
        this.studentName = Name;
        this.Grades = new double[quizGrades.length]; // use new to avoid REFERENCE LEAKS...

        for (int k = 0; k < quizGrades.length; k++)  //
            this.Grades[k] = quizGrades[k];          //

    }

    // Copy constructor:
    public Student(Student stu) {                               
        this(stu.ID, stu.studentName, stu.Grades);
    }

}
```

I made a copy of array `quizGrades` so there will not be a leak, but I am not sure whether the copy constructor is fine or not.

Comment: it doesn't seem like you are leaking, but I guess that depends on how you expose the Grades array to the outside.

Comment: This code is absolute `OK`. There is not any problem with memory leaking. You correctly make an `array deep copy`.`NPE` could be in some cases, but this is not the main point of the question.

Comment: try to use addValue and removeAt methods to handle array manipulation

Comment: @shmosel I guess we don't see all of the codes, so it's not quite sure that the class is immutable. A method like `getGrades(){ return this.Grades; }` and farewell immutability.

Comment: Consider using `System.arraycopy`.

Comment: @shmosel Immutable classes is out of scope of this question. I just want to say, that this code is correct according to JVM. Moreover - immutable classes is not a `magic` from any problem and you can use copy constructor to create a full copy of the object if you want to. This code is correct `according to JVM and this question`.